# How to change colorschemes only if a specific colorscheme is currently enabled?

Tags: colorscheme

I want to check if the colorscheme currently in use in Vim. For example, if I using `a` colorscheme, switch the colorscheme to `b`; else, do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least you should be able to check the global variable that holds the current color scheme...

```
:if g:colors_name ==? "a" | colo b | endif
```

`g:colors_name` is the variable that I'm talking about and we do a case-insensitive check against the scheme you mentioned, `a`. (Color schemes don't require you specify the correct case. Case-sensitive would be `==#`.)

`:colo` sets a new scheme, `b`, if there's a match.

Note the difference in quoting. `:colo` doesn't require any quotes.